# Laravel Email Verification 5.7

Tags: laravel, markdown, laravel-5.7

I implemented the email verification that Laravel offers out of the box but currently have an issue with the actionURL link added in the email footer. The button in the email has the correct link but the link in the footer displays ":actionURL"...

[image: actionUrl problem]

Part of the default laravel markdown for the email:

```
{{-- Action Button (button is working)--}}
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $actionUrl, 'color' => $color])
{{ $actionText }}
@endcomponent

{{-- Subcopy (the link has an issue)--}}
@component('mail::subcopy')
@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
'into your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
        'actionUrl' => $actionUrl
    ]
)
@endcomponent
```

Comment: This has been fixed, update your `laravel/framework` dependency to the latest version.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Created this project yesterday with no version flag if I check my composer.json "laravel/framework": "5.7.*"... What I'm I missing :/

Comment: What does `composer show` say for `laravel/framework`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir laravel/framework v5.7.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/22ca105c0b1759c95f79e553c1977ffd2a013d05) but not yet released.

Until Laravel 5.7.10 is released, you can apply the fix manually to your `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php` file:

```php
[
    'actionText' => $actionText,
    'actionURL' => $actionUrl,
]
```